# Call to a member function rowCount() on boolean-Php

Tags: php, sql, login

Buenas amigos soy nuevo por aca y espero formular bien esta pregunta 
estoy intentado hacer un login basado en roles ,los roles los tengo en una tabla aparte por lo que los traigo haciendo uso de inner join en la consulta 
solo quiero que ingrese por correo y clave este es el codigo pero al dar login me salta este error " Call to a member function rowCount() on boolean" 
como puedo corregirlo y gracias

```
<?php
  session_start();
    $correo=$_POST['correo'];
     $clave=md5($_POST['clave']);
      require_once('../php/cone.php');

      $query= "SELECT  id_usuario, nombre, apellido, correo, p.id_perfil, perfil FROM usuario u INNER JOIN perfil p ON p.id_perfil=u.id_perfil WHERE u.correo= $correo AND  u.clave= $clave"; 

      $resultado = $mysqli->query($query);



      if($resultado->rowCount()==1){
          $fila=$resultado->fetch();
          $_SESSION['idperfil']=$fila['id_perfil'];
         if($fila['id_perfil']==1)
         {
             header("Location: ../administrador/index.php");
         }
         if($fila['id_perfil']==2)
         {
             header("Location: ../aprendiz/index.php");
         }
         if($fila['id_perfil']==3)
         {  
             header("Location: ../root/index.php");
         }
      }
      else
      {
         echo "<font color='red'>Datos No Validos</font>";
      }

?>
```

Comment: Hola Furude, esta pregunta se ha realizado con anterioridad y ya tiene respuesta en el sitio. Busca e investiga en Stack Overflow en español y encontrarás la solución (lee [ask] para más información). Aparte de eso, el código que compartes es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL y no debería usarse en entornos de cara al público (lee sobre inyección SQL y consultas preparadas en MySQLi).

Answer (score 0):

`$resultado` te esta devolviendo `FALSE` porque la query da error.

El error es que faltan comillas en tu query.

```
$query= "SELECT  id_usuario, nombre, apellido, correo, p.id_perfil, perfil FROM usuario u INNER JOIN perfil p ON p.id_perfil=u.id_perfil WHERE u.correo= '$correo' AND  u.clave= '$clave'";
```

Ademas rowCount no existe. Tienes que usar num_rows

```
$resultado->num_rows
```

[Fuente num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Comment: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::rowCount()

Comment: rowCount no existe. Tienes que usar num_rows http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php Te lo añado a la respuesta

Comment: ya lo solucione muchas gracias ya redirige bien ahora como hago que un usuario que sea por ejemplo admin y entre no pueda entrar a usuarios por ejemplo es que tengo ese pequeño fallo me explico supongamos que yo haga login como admin entonces me manda a ruta/index y quiero entrar a usuario sin haber entrado en esta seccion pongo por ejemplo ruta2/index sin haber ingresado es posible corregir y gracias

Comment: Muchas gracias a los que me ayudaron anteriormente lamentablemente como soy nuevo no puedo dar puntos

Comment: @Furude Pero puedes marcar la respuesta como correcta, es decir en el check que aparece. Ya que esta fue la que te solucionó sería bueno que la puntues. Un saludo!

Comment: `rowCount` sí existe, pero es propio de PDO.